# Best way to allow multiple users to edit a node but require approval?

Tags: nodes

I am looking for a way to allow multiple "normal users" to suggest changes to existing nodes, but only once they are approved by admin, should they take effect. I am not sure how this would work in the case where multiple users make changes, but if stackoverflow and drupal stack exchange can do it, I'm sure it must be possible.

I had a look at [Node Changes](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodechanges), but its not technically ready. Is that the only option available to me?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the [revisioining](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning) module

[Revisioning](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning) is a module for the configuration of workflows to create, moderate and publish content revisions. You can set the role based permision for create , edit, view and delete revision of a content.